# When I do a release upgrade on a system with two derivatives, do both get updated?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-netbook, kubuntu

Let's say I installed regular Ubuntu Desktop edition using the liveCD. The I installed both Kubuntu and UNR on the same partition as Ubuntu desktop, by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-netbook
```

And they're all version 10.04. Now, if I log on to Ubuntu Desktop, and perform an upgrade to version 10.10 by doing `sudo do-release-upgrade`, will that upgrade Kubuntu and UNR as well?

I'm using Kubuntu and UNR as examples, but this question extends to all spin-offs. Does every installed version get upgraded when I upgrade one? Or do I have to manually upgrade them individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sure, you don't need to upgrade them separately. All parts of ubuntu will be upgraded at one pass.